# How to get city photo with google places api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-hooks, fetch, google-places-api

for my react weather-app i need to attach to every Card element that represents a city an img of that city.
besides downloading a lot of images, I found that google places can give me that info.
I registerd and got an api key from Google Cloud Platform.

here is my Card component:

p.s. - the https from herokuapp before the googleapi url is the only solution i found to deal with CORS error

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export default function CardUI({ apiKey, place }) {
    
    const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState('');
    
    useEffect( () => {
        fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/
json?place_id=${place}&fields=photo&key=${apiKey}`)
            .then(response =>response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setPhotoUrl(data);
                console.log(data);
            })
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={photoUrl} />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                    the card's content.
                </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to have any special things or libraries. Simply put the ImagesAPI in the src tag then it's done all the images would be loaded easily without any effort.

```
 const ref = props.item.photos[0].photo_reference;
 setimg(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400
         &photoreference=${ref}&key=${APIKEY}`
       );
```

Access Image in SRC tag

```
 <img src={img} alt="" />
```

Or in a simple way

```
 <img 
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400
           &photoreference=reference&key=APIKEY"
      alt=""
  />
```

Comment: this is the most elegant one liner way to do it, and it works

Comment: @Parshuram Reddy there's a little typo in the URL that you have provided. There has to be a '?' between 'photo' and 'maxwidth'.

Comment: Yes, I agree that. Thanks @TanmayVij.

Answer (score 0):

Your CORS error might be because you are using Places photos webservice requests. You can use the [Places Library of Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos) for client side services.

Here's a sample where I use Autocomplete to give you a suggestion in the place you want to see then once you chose the address, it will get the place details and you can get the URL of the place. Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kzq6ey?file=App.js) and below is the code snippet:

```
/* global google */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const CardUI = () => {
  const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    createScriptLoadMap();
  }, []);

  const initialize = () => {
    let placeSearch;
    let autocomplete;
    //use Places Autocomplete
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
      { types: ["geocode"] }
    );
    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function () {
      placeSearch = autocomplete.getPlace();
      //set photoURL from Places photos result
      setPhotoUrl(
        placeSearch.photos[0].getUrl({ maxWidth: 350, maxHeight: 350 })
      );
    });
  };

  const createScriptLoadMap = () => {
    var gScript = document.querySelector("[data-setted]");
    var isSetted = gScript && gScript.getAttribute("data-setted");

    if (!isSetted) {
      var index = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src =
        "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.setAttribute("data-setted", true);
      index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
      window.initialize = initialize;
    } else {
      initialize();
    }
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div id="locationField">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
      </div>
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={photoUrl} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </main>
  );
};

export default CardUI;
```

Comment: Thanks!... when I was googeling the solution to my problem, all I saw was this autocomplete google places...is this the only way to get a url photo? to impliment an input tag and search? there is no solution for knkows places ahead?

Comment: You can use the [Place Details Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests) if you have a known placeID. Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n6yneu?file=App.js)